# Time Machine menu bar Icon Location

Tags: macos, time-machine, menu-bar

I'm trying to find the Time Machine menu bar icon resource so I can change how it looks a bit. Where is that icon? In Time Machine's package contents > resources, all I see is `backup.icns` (the Finder icon), `menu.plist`, and 33 `.lproj` folders for different languages. In the English folder is a single file called `Menu.strings`.

Answer (score 4):

The Time Machine menu bar item is located at:

```
/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/TimeMachine.menu/
```

The menu bar item uses four PDFs for the four different icon states, in `Contents/Resources/`:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

<sup>Above icons from OS X 10.10 Yosemite DP2</sup>

Comment: Are these out of OS X Yosemite? Cause on my Mavericks these certainly look different …

Comment: @Asmus Yes they are. The menu bar item itself looks the same as it was in Mavericks as far as I can remember though.